# Как с помощью класса указать координаты кнопок?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

как с помощью класса указать координаты кнопок (`ООП`) с помощью библиотеки `jQuery`. может есть какие-либо примеры

Comment: что есть "(ООП)"?

Comment: объекто-ориентированное программирование

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```js
$("#sq").click(function() {
  $(this).offset({
    top: 80,
    left: 50
  });
});
```

```css
#sq {
  background: #ffe620;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Клик по квадрату меняет его координаты</p>
  <div id="sq"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#sq").click(function () {
    $(this).offset({top:80, left:50});
});
```

Источник: [ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=55](http://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=55)

Comment: почему без ООП?

Comment: @Igor, а почему без ооп? :-) jQuery объект возвращает, `this` объект, `click` метод объекта, кругом одни объекты :-) Очевидно что тут явная ориентация на объекты :)

Answer (score 2):

Ну `ООП` так `ООП`

```js
function Button($el) {
  this.$el = $el;
  this.coords = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }
}

Button.prototype.setCoords = function(x, y) {
  this.coords = {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
}

Button.prototype.update = function() {
  this.$el.offset({
    top: this.coords.x,
    left: this.coords.y
  });
}

var $buttonEl = $('#btn');
var buttonInstance = new Button($buttonEl);

function moveButton() {
  buttonInstance.setCoords(50, 100);
  buttonInstance.update()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="moveButton()" id="btn">Передвинуть меня</button>
```

Comment: а зачем элемент в классе кнопки? :)

Comment: @Grundy, в данном случае, каждый экземпляр относится к одному DOM элементу